# Finding a duplication of an integer pattern in an array list

Tags: java, arraylist

I have to find a pattern in the array that I am creating and then stop adding numbers to the array when the pattern is seen to be duplicated twice. The pattern that I am trying to find is 4-2-1, so when that is repeated twice in a row in this arithmetic sequence, the program is finished. Currently my output gives me one sequence of the pattern with an error following: [10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 0

**YES I HAVE TRIED TO DEBUG USING ECLIPSE BUT I AM STILL STUCK So if someone could help me figure out why it is only printing the sequence with one repetition of the pattern at the end, that would help me profusely. Thanks. My code:

```
Scanner inData = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
    ArrayList<Integer> list= new ArrayList<Integer>();

        while (inData.hasNext())
        {

            int numA=inData.nextInt(); 
            int var;
            boolean done=false;


            list.add(numA);

            while(!done)
            {
                var=list.size();

                for(int i=var;i>0;i--)
                {
                    numA=list.get(var-1);
                    if(numA%2==0)
                    {
                        numA/=2;
                        list.add(numA);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        numA=(numA*3)+1;
                        list.add(numA);
                    }
                    var=list.size();

                    if (var>6)
                    {
                    for(int j=1;j>=6;j++)
                    {
                        if(list.get(var-1)==1)
                        {
                            if(list.get(var-4)==1)
                            {
                                if(list.get(var-2)==2)
                                    {
                                        if(list.get(var-5)==2)
                                        {
                                            if(list.get(var-3)==4)
                                            {
                                                if(list.get(var-6)==4)
                                                {
                                                    done=true;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                            }

                    }

                }

                System.out.print(list);
                list.clear(); 
            }

        }

    }Scanner inData = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
    ArrayList<Integer> list= new ArrayList<Integer>();

        while (inData.hasNext())
        {

            int numA=inData.nextInt(); 
            int var;
            boolean done=false;


            list.add(numA);

            while(!done)
            {
                var=list.size();

                for(int i=var;i>0;i--)
                {
                    numA=list.get(var-1);
                    if(numA%2==0)
                    {
                        numA/=2;
                        list.add(numA);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        numA=(numA*3)+1;
                        list.add(numA);
                    }
                    var=list.size();

                    if (var>6)
                    {
                    for(int j=1;j>=6;j++)
                    {
                        if(list.get(var-1)==1)
                        {
                            if(list.get(var-4)==1)
                            {
                                if(list.get(var-2)==2)
                                    {
                                        if(list.get(var-5)==2)
                                        {
                                            if(list.get(var-3)==4)
                                            {
                                                if(list.get(var-6)==4)
                                                {
                                                    done=true;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                            }

                    }

                }

                System.out.print(list);
                list.clear(); 
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: What line throws the exception? Then ask yourself how `list` could be empty at that point.

Comment: @TedHopp  numA=list.get(var-1);

Comment: @TedHopp Sorry, I dont understand the second part of your comment, could you explain

Comment: You are calling `list.clear()` inside the loop that relies on `var` being equal to the list length. Please indent your code correctly and you will see that you have a number of what appear to me to be structural errors like this.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is using `Collections.indexOfSubList`. Something like this.

```
int a [] = {4,2,1,4,2,1};
if(Collections.indexOfSubList(list, Arrays.asList(a))!=-1){
       return true;
}
return false
```

Comment: What does that method do?

Comment: Please read the api(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#indexOfSubList%28java.util.List,%20java.util.List%29)

Comment: Why is it return true if it does not pick up the pattern?

Comment: It returns true when it picks up the pattern. In other word when the index value is not - 1

Answer (score 0):

Well, there appear to be a few errors with your code.

I'm going to enumerate some here: fix as many as possible, then check to see if your code works.

1. `int i=var; i>0; i--`. Since `var` is the size of your array, it is outside the bounds. Java uses 0-based arrays, meaning that valid indeces are in the range [0,size-1] (inclusive). Replace with `int i=var - 1; i >= 0; i--`
2. The `j` loop does nothing but prevent anything from happening (nothing can enter, since you start at 1 and immediately break the loop by imposing the restriction `>=6` and `j` is never used. Remove the loop.

Comment: I did the first comment, but it put the code into an endless loop. For the second comment, if I removed the entire loop, then how would the array stop when it reaches that 421421?

Comment: Disregard the first part of my comment, I typed it in wrong, but im still stuck on the second one

Comment: Can you post your txt file?

Comment: text file just says 10